# Get text from UIPickerview and move Textfield inside UIAlert

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxcpc.jpg). I have other alerts with textfields and others with picker views but doing one with both is a pain.

```
let gradeTypeTextField = gradeTypeTextField (Doesn't work)

var gradeTypeTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func newGrade(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 When button is tapped, show alert.
    alertForGrade()
}

var gradeType = ["Attendance", "Assignment", "Homework Assignment", "Quiz", "Test", "Mid-Term", "Exam", "Other"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     Hide extra cells
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

}


func alertForGrade() {

     Create the alert controller.
 alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Grade", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert);


    Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert?.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (gradeTypeTextField) -> Void in

        gradeTypeTextField.placeholder = "Type of Grade."

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
        gradeTypeTextField.inputView = pickerView
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    })

    alert?.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (assignmentTextField) -> Void in
        assignmentTextField.placeholder = "Name of the assignment."

    })

    alert?.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (gradeTextField) -> Void in gradeTextField.placeholder = "Grade for the assignment."

        Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            let assignmenttextField = (self.alert?.textFields![0])! as UITextField

            let gradeTextField = (self.alert?.textFields![1])! as UITextField
            let assignment = assignmenttextField.text!

            let gradeString = gradeTextField.text!

            let grade = Int(gradeString)

            self.dictionaryForGradebook.updateValue(grade!, forKey: assignment)

            print(self.dictionaryForGradebook)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })


        self.alert?.addAction(ok)
        self.alert?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in


        }))

        // 4. Present the alert.
        self.present(self.alert!, animated: true, completion: nil)


    })


}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return gradeType.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return gradeType[row]
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

This prints but if I try " yearTextField.text = years[row]" it crashes.
           print("Testinggggg") 

    self.view.endEditing(true)


}
```

Where is the isuue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to reference your created `UITextField` later when you attempt to add text to it when you select a row in the `UIPicker`. You seem to be forgetting to place that link:

```
alert?.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (gradeTypeTextField) -> Void in

    // Append this: 
    self.gradeTypeTextField = gradeTypeTextField

    gradeTypeTextField.placeholder = "Type of Grade."

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    gradeTypeTextField.inputView = pickerView
    self.view.endEditing(true)

})
```

This will however create a retain-cycle so it is recommend to create an unowned/weak self link by adding `[weak self]` to the start of your closure.

Comment: In this function:   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
// The print statement works but the other code cause a crash
   gradeTypeTextField.text = gradeType[row] 
           print("Testinggggg") 

    self.view.endEditing(true)


}